# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Please pass numbers as strings or BigNumber

Tags: web3js, react

I want to convert the allocation amount to BN, but I have no success.

Here is my code:

```
    const amount = web3.utils.toWei("1");

    const busdPAir = await panCakeRouter.methods.getAmountsOut(amount, [WBNB, BUSD]).call();
    const uniTotalOutputSell = await panCakeRouter.methods.getAmountsOut(amount, [WBNB, SAFE]).call();

    const totalSupply = await ssContract.methods.totalSupply().call();
    const deadBalance = await ssContract.methods.balanceOf("0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dead").call();

    const totalSupplyBN = web3.utils.toBN(totalSupply);
    const deadSupplyBN = web3.utils.toBN(deadBalance);
    const circSupply = totalSupplyBN.sub(deadSupplyBN);

    const circ = Math.round(web3.utils.fromWei(circSupply.toString(), 'nanoether'));
    const dead = Math.round(web3.utils.fromWei(deadBalance, 'nanoether'));
    const oneBNB = Math.round(web3.utils.fromWei(uniTotalOutputSell[1], 'nanoether'));

    const price1bnb = Math.round(web3.utils.fromWei(busdPAir[1], 'micro'));
    const priceFor1BNB = (price1bnb / oneBNB).toString();
    const priceFor1ss = priceFor1BNB.replace(".0", ".0000000");
    const shortPrice = priceFor1BNB.slice(0, 6);
    const shortCirc = Math.round(circ / 1000000);

    totalSupplyEl.innerHTML = "10,000,000,000,000,000";
    circSupplyEl.innerHTML = formatAmount(circ);
    burnedSupplyEl.innerHTML = formatAmount(dead);
    priceBNBEl.innerHTML = formatAmount(oneBNB);
    marketCapEl.innerHTML = "$" + formatAmount(Math.round(shortCirc * (shortPrice - 0)));
    priceSpotEl.innerHTML = "$" + shortPrice;
    priceSpot1El.innerHTML = '$' + priceFor1ss.slice(0, 12) + '<span class="usd">USD</span>';
```

What is the best way to manage error?

Comment: At which line u get the error?

Comment: const oneBNB = Math.round(web3.utils.fromWei(uniTotalOutputSell[1], 'nanoether'));